# Can't send a labNumber into an sql query

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I'm very confused as to why my _labNumber variable isn't getting sent into the method that I am using to call an SQL query, as it works for other methods in the same class. I have a try catch block in my class that calls the methods where I pass in _labNumber(This is correctly assigned, I have triple checked it)

```
try:
            _comment = self.dataServices.GetComment(_labNumber)
            _value2 = self.dataServices.GetValue2(_labNumber)
            _value1 = self.dataServices.GetValue1(_labNumber)
            _results = self.dataServices.getResults(_labNumber)
        except AttributeError:
            _comment = None
            _value2 = None
            _value1 = None
            _results = None
```

This is one of the methods in the class that is being used to retrieve the data from the database:

```
def GetValue2(self, _LabNumber):
    _LabNumberStr = str(_LabNumber)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as _cursor:
            _cursor.execute("{CALL dbo.uspShireXGetValue2(%s)}", [_LabNumberStr])
            row = _cursor.fetchone()
            if row:
                return {'VALUE2': row[0]}#21
            else:
                return {'VALUE2': None}
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle or log the exception as appropriate
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return {'VALUE2': None}
```

And finally here is the query that I know works as it returns the data when I hard code a lab number:

```
@LabNumber VARCHAR(10)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT
    WDR.COMMENT
FROM dbo.DNA_WORKSHEET_DET WD
INNER JOIN dbo.DNA_WORKSHEET W ON WD.WORKSHEET = W.WORKSHEET
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DNA_TEST T ON W.TEST = T.TEST
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DNA_LAB_TEST LT ON WD.LABNO = LT.LABNO AND W.TEST = LT.TEST
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DNA_WORKSHEET_DET_RESULT WDR ON WD.WORKSHEET = WDR.WORKSHEET AND WD.LANE = WDR.LANE
WHERE WD.LABNO = @LabNumber
return
```

It is returning the error 'An error occurred: not enough arguments for format string
' any help toward fixing this will be much appreciated, as I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of days now.
Here is the full stack trace as requested:

```
None
[28/Feb/2024 11:12:13] "GET /Molecular/SolidCancer/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=8hPU3Tfu7mwUNfvNfQSWMYjwy2jEldjJsUh8MUMQ0kT1nmNixlLhkqMOqJmLsV0f&txtCriteriaDateFrom=2019-12-30&txtCriteriaDateTo=2024-03-29&ddlCriteriaStatus=NOTFINAL&txtCriteriaLabnumber=&txtCriteriaLastname=&ddlCriteriaPriority=&ddlCriteriaDiseaseIndication1=&ddlCriteriaDiseaseIndication2=&ddlCriteriaDiseaseIndication3=&ddlAlertCriteria=False&ddlCriteriaReasonForDiseaseIndication1=&ddlCriteriaReasonForDiseaseIndication2=&ddlCriteriaReasonForDiseaseIndication3=&txtPageNumber=1&ddlCriteriaNoResult=0&ddlCriteriaItemsPerPage=20&btnSubmit=Search HTTP/1.1" 200 175938
[28/Feb/2024 11:12:14] "GET /static/Styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[28/Feb/2024 11:12:14] "GET /static/Scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[28/Feb/2024 11:12:14] "GET /static/js/Scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Comment: `execute()` params [must be a iteratable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), try wrapping in a list `_cursor.execute("{CALL dbo.uspShireXGetValue2(%s)}", [_LabNumberStr])`

Comment: When you post about an error, you should show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the parameter(s) in a list, so:

```
def GetValue2(self, _LabNumber):
    _LabNumberStr = str(_LabNumber)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as _cursor:
            _cursor.execute('{CALL dbo.uspShireXGetValue2(%s)}', [_LabNumberStr])
            row = _cursor.fetchone()
            if row:
                return {'VALUE2': row[0]}  # 21
            else:
                return {'VALUE2': None}
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle or log the exception as appropriate
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return {'VALUE2': None}
```

that being said, please *don't* make raw queries. By working with a `QuerySet`, you can further manipulate the same query: i.e. paginating, filtering, annotating. A raw query does not allow that.

Comment: You are a saint, that has gotten rid of my error message, which is one step closer to success that I was this morning, I'll make sure to refactor my code with the suggestions that you have given me about the query set. Thank you